# Finding google shared drive folder ID

Tags: python, google-drive-api

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth) 
def get_children(root_folder_id,param={'q': str},drive=drive):
    
    str = "\'" + root_folder_id + "\'" + " in parents and trashed=false"
    param["q"]=str
    file_list = drive.ListFile(param).GetList()
    return file_list

def get_folder_id(root_folder_id, root_folder_title,drive=drive):
    file_list = get_children(root_folder_id,drive=drive)
    for file in file_list:
        if(file['title'] == root_folder_title):
            return file['id']
get_folder_id("root", "YourFolderNameInRoot",drive=drive)
```

After testing, this cannot be used to find the name of a shared Drive Folder ID. Only okay for "MyDrive"

How do I find google SHARED drive folder ID.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing the documentation of `pydrive`, `pydrive` does not support the [Drive.Drives.List](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list) method of **Google Drive API**.

`Drive.Drives.List` will list the user's shared drives which include the name and id of the shared drive as part of the response.

**Example:**

[image]

Here is an example usage of [Drive.Drives.List](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-shareddrives#recover_a_shared_drive_that_doesnt_have_an_organizer) in python.

### Further Reading:

- [Google Drive Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)